# How to disable a button in datagrid asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I just want to ask how can I disable the first button (the one with "Test1") in datagrid (see attached picture).

Below is my code in aspx page

[image]

Please help in creating the codes in its code behind.

```
<asp:datagrid id="RecordsGrid" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0" BorderWidth="0" Width="100%" GridLines="None">
<SelectedItemStyle CssClass="selecteditem"></SelectedItemStyle> 
<AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="alternatingitem"></AlternatingItemStyle>
<ItemStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="item"></ItemStyle> 
<HeaderStyle CssClass="headerdatagrid"></HeaderStyle> 
<FooterStyle CssClass="footerline"></FooterStyle> 
<Columns> 
<asp:ButtonColumn Text="View/Update" CommandName="Button1">
</asp:ButtonColumn> 
</Columns> 
</asp:datagrid>
```

Comment: Please, use 'edit' button to add information inside your question. Comment is not the right place to add information about your question. Also, code is simply unreadable in your comment (so when you will edit your question to add code, take care about new lines and indentation)

Comment: @Garf365 I do appreciate the correction Thanks! :) Also, may I ask if you can help me with this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to help you on this king of topic. I just help you to write question which has more chance to be answered

Comment: @Garf365 It's okay :) I hope someone can help me with this problem :)